# Python - Array becomes scalar variable when passed into function

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a simple python script that when given a photo, first converts it to greyscale and then will band it into a number of colors. For example if the number of colours passed in is 2, the greyscale image will be changed so that each pixel is either pitch black (0) or bright white (255).

However, when calling my function 'getGreyscaleValue' used to determine the greyscale value of each pixel, I am getting an error. It seems that when passing the arrays, 'bandWidthArray' and 'colorsArray' into the function, they change from arrays to a scalar variable '0.0'. Running the following script and observing the printed values, should replicate the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

numberOfColors = 2;
greyscaleRange=255;

col = Image.open("IMG_5525.JPG")
gray = col.convert('L') # Make grayscale

y=np.asarray(gray.getdata(),dtype=np.float64).reshape((gray.size[1],gray.size[0]))

def getGreyScaleValue(x, bandWidthArray, colorsArray):
    print(bandWidthArray)
    print(colorsArray)
    for i in range(1, bandWidthArray.len):
        if(int(round(x))<int(round(bandWidthArray[i]))):
            return colorsArray[i-1]
    return 255

bandWidthArray = np.linspace(0, greyscaleRange, numberOfColors+1)
colorsArray = np.linspace(0, greyscaleRange, numberOfColors)
getGreyScaleValue = np.vectorize(getGreyScaleValue)

print(bandWidthArray)
print(colorsArray)

y = getGreyScaleValue(y, bandWidthArray, colorsArray)

y=np.asarray(y,dtype=np.uint8) #if values still in range 0-255!
w=Image.fromarray(y,mode='L')
w.save('out.jpg')
```

Stack trace is as follows:

```
PS C:\python\pythonimages> python imgChange1.py
[   0.   127.5  255. ]
[   0.  255.]
0.0
0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imgChange1.py", line 27, in <module>
    y = getGreyScaleValue(y, bandWidthArray, colorsArray)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2734, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2804, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)

  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2764, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
  File "imgChange1.py", line 15, in getGreyScaleValue
    for i in range(1, bandWidthArray.len):
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'len'
```

Comment: please include the error msg you received.  replication, while important, can only be attempted when we know the actual error.  in many cases the cause can be determined by examining the code coupled with awareness of the error.

Comment: @ShpielMeister, I have edited the post to include the stacktrace - thank you for the help!

Comment: np.  i've provided an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for i in range(1, bandWidthArray.len):
```

to:

```
for i in range(1, len(bandWidthArray)):
```

NumPy arrays don't have a `len` method.

Furthermore, don't vectorize your function. Remove this line:

```
getGreyScaleValue = np.vectorize(getGreyScaleValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, bandWidthArray.len):
```

can be changed to

```
for i in range(1, bandWidthArray.size):


>>> qa = np.array([1,3,5])
>>> qa.size
3
```